# Scala closures on wikipedia

Tags: scala, closures

Found the following snippet on the [Closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29) page on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/)

```
//# Return a list of all books with at least 'threshold' copies sold.
def bestSellingBooks(threshold: Int) = bookList.filter(book => book.sales >= threshold)
//# or
def bestSellingBooks(threshold: Int) = bookList.filter(_.sales >= threshold)
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but this isn't a closure? It is a function literal, an anynomous function, a lambda function, but not a closure?

Comment: Why is threshold a closed term? It's a local variable that is captured by the function when it is passed to the filter method, no?

Comment: you are right. threshold is not a closed term, its free variable and the closure is an open term.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well... if you want to be technical, this is a function literal which is translated at runtime into a closure, closing the open terms (binding them to a val/var in the scope of the function literal). Also, in the context of this function literal (`_.sales >= threshold`), `threshold` is a *free* variable, as the function literal itself doesn't give it any meaning. By itself, `_.sales >= threshold` is an *open term* At runtime, it is bound to the local variable of the function, each time the function is called.

Take this function for example, generating closures:

```
def makeIncrementer(inc: Int): (Int => Int) = (x: Int) => x + inc
```

At runtime, the following code produces 3 closures. It's also interesting to note that b and c are not the same closure (`b == c` gives `false`).

```
val a = makeIncrementer(10)
val b = makeIncrementer(20)
val c = makeIncrementer(20)
```

I still think the example given on wikipedia is a good one, albeit not quite covering the whole story. It's quite hard giving an example of actual closures by the strictest definition without actually a memory dump of a program running. It's the same with the class-object relation. You usually give an example of an object by defining a `class Foo { ...` and then instantiating it with `val f = new Foo`, saying that f is the object.

`-- Flaviu Cipcigan`

Notes:

- Reference: Programming in Scala, Martin Odersky, Lex Spoon, Bill Venners
- Code compiled with Scala version 2.7.5.final running on Java 1.6.0_14.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure, but I think you're right. Doesn't a closure require state (I guess free variables...)?

Or maybe the bookList is the free variable?

Comment: "Scala's type inference system automatically recognizes the argument to filter to be a function that takes a book and returns a Boolean value and turns it into a closure".

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, this is a closure that contains a formal parameter, ***threshold*** and context variable, ***bookList***, from the enclosing scope. So the return value(List[Any]) of the function may change while applying the filter predicate function. It is varying based on the elements of List(bookList) variable from the context.